# Count of people by hour

Tags: sql

I need some help working out how many people were on site for each hour.

The data looks like this

```
Id  Roomid, NumPeople, Starttime,        Closetime.
    1   1       4          2018/10/03 09:06  2018/10/03 12:43
    2   2       8          2018/10/03 10:16  2018/10/03 13:12
    3   1       6          2018/10/03 13:02  2018/10/03 15:01
```

What I need out is the max count of people during the hour, each hour

```
Time   |    PeoplePresent
9           4
10          12
11          12
12          12
13          14
14          6
15          6
```

Getting the count of people as the arrived is simple enough, but I can’t think where to start to get the presence for each hour.  Can anyone suggest a strategy for this.  I ok with the simple SQL stuff but I’m certain this requires some advanced SQL functions.

Comment: What SQL do you currently have written?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested the following in SQL Server 2008 R2:

You can use a recursive CTE to build the list of hours, including the row id and NumPeople values. Then you can sum them together to get your final output. I put together the following test data based on the question.

```
CREATE TABLE #times 
(
    Id int 
    , Roomid INT
    , NumPeople INT
    , Starttime DATETIME
    ,  Closetime DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO #times
(
    Id
    ,Roomid
    ,NumPeople
    ,Starttime
    ,Closetime
)
VALUES
(1, 1, 4 , '2018/10/03 09:06', '2018/10/03 12:43')
,(2, 2, 8, '2018/10/03 10:16', '2018/10/03 13:12')
,(3, 1, 6, '2018/10/03 13:02', '2018/10/03 15:01')

;WITH recursive_CTE (id, startHour, currentHour, diff, NumPeople) AS
(
    SELECT
        Id
        ,startHour   = DATEPART(HOUR, t.Starttime)
        ,currentHour = DATEPART(HOUR, t.Starttime)
        ,diff        = DATEDIFF(HOUR, Starttime, Closetime)
        ,t.NumPeople
    FROM #times t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        r.id
        ,r.startHour
        ,r.currentHour + 1
        ,r.diff
        ,r.NumPeople
    FROM recursive_CTE r
    WHERE r.currentHour < startHour + diff
)
SELECT
    Time           = currentHour
    ,PeoplePresent = SUM(NumPeople)
FROM recursive_CTE
GROUP BY currentHour

DROP TABLE #times
```

Query results:

```
Time    PeoplePresent
9       4
10      12
11      12
12      12
13      14
14      6
15      6
```